# add and remove dynamic rows with multiple elements in thymleaf and bind with list

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a pojo class with object array list and i want to bind it with dynamically created elements using jquery.

below is my pojo class

```
public class EmployeeTaskWarpper {

    private Long id;
    
    private Long mid;
    
    private List<Employee> emplist;

    //getter setter

}
```

below is my controller class method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/newEmployeeTasks", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newTasksForm(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        
        List<AllEmployess> namelist = credentialsService.findAllEmployees();
        modelAndView.addObject("namelist", namelist);
        EmployeeTaskWarpper emptasks = new EmployeeTaskWarpper();
        List<Employee> tasklist = new ArrayList<Employee>(20);
        emptasks.setTasklist(tasklist);
        modelAndView.addObject("tasklist", tasklist );
        modelAndView.setViewName("new-Task");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

below is my thymleaf code,

```
<form th:action="@{/createTasks}" method="post" th:object="${tasklist}">
    <div id="div_1" class="dyngroup" th:each="taske , stat : ${tasklist.emplist}">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
            <label>Assigned to Employee</label> 
            <select class="form-control" th:field="*{emplist[__${stat.index}__].employeeid}">
            <option value="0">Select Employee</option>
            <option th:each="name : ${namelist}" th:value="${name.emp_Id}"                        th:text="${name.employeeName}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">           
            <label>description</label> 
            <input type="text" th:field="*{emplist[__${stat.index}__].description}>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-10 col-sm-10 col-lg-10"></div>
<div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2">
<button class="btn btn-warning btn-xl" onclick="add()" type="button">Add</button>
</div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-space btn-primary new-team-submit-button">Create</button>
</form>
```

below is jquery code to add dynamic rows,

```
<script>
    
    function add() {
    
      // Finding total number of elements added
      var total_element = $(".dyngroup").length;
        
      // last <div> with element class id
      var lastid = $(".dyngroup:last").attr("id");
      var split_id = lastid.split("_");
      var nextindex = Number(split_id[1]) + 1;
      
      var max = 5;
      // Check total number elements
      if(total_element < max ){
     
       // Adding new div container after last occurance of element class
       $(".dyngroup:last").after("<div class='dyngroup' id='div_"+ nextindex +"'></div>");
     
       // Adding element to <div>
       $("#div_" + nextindex).append(
       "<div class='container-fluid'>"
       + "<div class='form-group row'>"
       + "<div class='col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3'>"
       + "<label>Assigned to Employee</label>" 
       + "<select class='form-control' th:field="+ *{emplist[nextindex].employeeid} +">"
       + "<option value='0'>Select Employee</option>"
       + "<option th:each='name : ${namelist}' th:value='${name.emp_Id}' th:text='${name.employeeName}'></option>"
       + "</select>"
       + "</div>"
       + "<div class='col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3'>"
       + "<label>description</label>" 
       + "<input type='text' th:field=" + *{emplist[__${stat.index}__].description} +">"
       + "</div>"
       + "</div>"
       + "</div>");
    }
    }
    
     // Remove element
     function remove(id){
      
      var split_id = id.split("_");
      var deleteindex = split_id[1];

      // Remove <div> with id
      $("#div_" + deleteindex).remove();

     }
    
    
    
    </script>
```

the issue is , i cannot render thymleaf code. i also added size of arraylist in controller but still cannot render code.

Can anyone please guide me in right direction.

Answer (score 1):

When you insert inputs with jQuery don't use th: attributes!

Thymeleaf is templating engine. While obtaining a view from server every th: elements are evaluated to plain HTML. That means in generated view none of element has th: attributes. So you can't simply add dynamically th: attributes with jQuery, because at this point it means nothing.

In your script you should replace attributes like th:field="+ *{emplist[nextindex].employeeid} to the name="emplist[' + nextindex + '].employeeid"

instead of writing th:field you can write name: only( name="emplist[' + nextindex + '].employeeid")

```
 + "<select class='form-control' name="emplist[' + nextindex + '].employeeid">"

 + "<input type='text' name=" emplist[' + nextindex + '].description">"
```